# How do I choose a NIC to use for iSCSI?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi

I am standing up a new file server and I need to connect it to my iSCSI SAN and I am looking for a good NIC to use for dedicated iSCSI with multi-pathing. What should I be looking for in a good dual-NIC card to dedicate to iSCSI?

Here is what I have so far in my list:

- adjust MTU beyond defaults
- hardware offloads for iSCSI tagged traffic
- must be GigE

Are there things I should avoid?

Comment: The current way this is written, will probably mean that it will get closed as a shopping question.  Try and re-word it so it is less subjective.  Don't ask for a particular product.  Ask something like what feature(s) are does a nic need to have for iSCSI to work well.  Ask how to tell what NIC will be great for iSCSI.

Comment: Edited to ask a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would never use Broadcom for anything without first reading this:

http://blog.serverfault.com/post/broadcom-die-mutha/

Comment: I have had some issues with Broadcom gear in the past, specifically in hyper-v machines on Dell hardware. The solution was to replace the Broadcom NICs with Intel. I'm looking to see if someone has a suggestion on a good NIC to use for iSCSI.